# unable to install and use /whisk.system/alarms on openwhisk locally set up on ubuntu

Tags: openwhisk, serverless

I am seeing the following error:

bin/wsk package get --summary /whisk.system/alarms --insecure
error: Unable to get package 'alarms': The supplied authentication is not authorized to access this resource. (code 7320)

I am using the guest authentication

(I have downloaded the openwhisk source on my Ubuntu 16.04 machine and installed it using ./gradlew distDocker).

Other features are working: action, triggers, rules, etc.

Tried downloading /whisk.system/alarms from github, and ran installCatalog.sh - it gave EOF for a POST request:

~/openwhisk-package-alarms$ ./installCatalog.sh $AUTH_KEY $API_HOST $API_HOST $API_PORT $API_HOST
error: Package update failed: Put https://172.17.0.1:5984/api/v1/namespaces/_/packages/alarms?overwrite=true: EOF
techie@serverless02:~/openwhisk-package-alarms$

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup alarm package.
Please refer to https://github.com/apache/incubator-openwhisk-package-alarms

Answer (score 0):

There isn't easy to follow documentation yet. I wrote notes on how to install on Vagrant here: https://github.com/apache/incubator-openwhisk-package-alarms/issues/51#issuecomment-294010619

Comment: Thank. This helps set up the alarm. But bin/wsk trigger create convertTriggerPeriodic --feed /whisk.system/alarms/alarm -p cron "* * * * *" --insecure command gives: "code": 25622,
                "error": "There was an error processing your request."  ok: deleted trigger convertTriggerPeriodic  -- Even if I give a valid trigger payload, same response. What should be the command to associate the above (periodic) trigger with an action? Before even before the trigger is created, it is deleted.